# Can we create bag of words for texture/color feature in java opencv?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to do Flower classification, I have extracted 3 features from flower image; Texture using MR8 filter, color using HSV color model, Shape using SIFT. here are the images

Now i want to create visual vocabulary of all these three features. i am done with [Shape Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657358/weka-tool-multiboostab-classifier-in-java-eclipse) (SIFT descriptor) 
How can i do it with texture and color individually and finally i also want the combine all features for classification.

Comment: Do you have the algorithm in java, completed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use k-means(or other clustering algorithm) to get the visual vocabularies for each feature space respectively (just the same as you did using sift).

Before you combine these three features, you should convert an image into a high-level representation, such as bag-of-word representation.

Thus, each image will represent as a histogram, since you use three features, there will be three histograms, then you can obtain a combined feature by **concatenating** these three histograms, which is so called **late fusion**.

You can check more details in [1].

[1]: A Visual Vocabulary for Flower Classification, CVPR 06

Comment: thank you i have implemented the same [1] in javacv using multiboost classifier